# How can I forward multiple email at once on Yahoo!7 Mail?

Tags: email-forwarding, yahoo-mail

My sister asked me if she can forward 40 emails in one go. She uses Yahoo!7. I had a look and it seems to me that there is no option like that...

Any idea how to deal with such a request?

Comment: I thought I could use pop3 or imap and some external email client that would do the 'hard' job for me. But I couldn't find any pop3/imap settings for Yahoo mail ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it's not possible via Yahoo!'s web interface. When I select multiple messages in my inbox and click `Forward`, Yahoo! gives the following error:

[image]

However, there is [YPOPs!](http://www.ypopsemail.com) which is a free open source software that provides POP3 and SMTP access to Yahoo! Mail. In this way, you can forward multiple emails at once by making use of an email software.

Comment: I thought so but what about some kind of workaround? :-)

Comment: Perhaps [YPops!](http://ypopsemail.com/) can help you.

Comment: @Radek: OK, I updated my answer.